# System call from method (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, system, call

I need make system call from method of Ruby of Rails , but I want it to stay on the same page.
Right now for some reason it does not execute , but shows :

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/devices/22918"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This is the button:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/glossy_green_button.png"), device , :method => :turnon, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

This is method:

```
def turnon
@device = Device.find(params[:id])
result = `/perl/toggle.pl @device.infodot on`
end
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong,

thank you

D

Comment: If you want the user to stay on the same page, shouldn't you use ajax? The link_to is signaling to your rails app that there is a new page you want the user to visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply not using the `method` correctly. You're using it to target the `action` of the controller you want to execute (note that I explicitly said action and not method for clarity).
Available actions in a controller are defined by your `routes.rb` file.You should eventually read or re read [that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

In your case, let's say you have a resource `device` (I guess this is what you have), you'll first create a new action in your `routes.rb` file

```
resources :devices do
  put :turnon, on: :member
end
```

You can read doc about this syntax [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) but basically I'm making the action `turnon` available via the `HTTP PUT method` on each devices, meaning that it will be accessible through the URL `/devices/1/turnon` or via the `url_helper` : `turnon_device_path` (or `turnon_device_url`)

I assume that your turnon action will modify existing things, not creating new things, that's why I'm using the `PUT` verb

Then the link will look something like :

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/glossy_green_button.png"), turnon_device_path(device) , :method => :put, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

see that the method is the HTTP method corresponding to the new route I created.

I also assume that you put the `turnon` method in the `DevicesController`.

Finally as you want to do that in ajax, you can have a look a the `remote: true` [option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: Don't need column after put I guess, thank you , it seems to be closer  to working , but it loading for 5 minutes for some reason. And then `Template is missing

Missing template devices/turnon, application/turnon with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/var/www/ruby/reservation/app/views"`

Comment: just noticed I had made a typo it's : `put :turnon, on: :member` not `put:`

Comment: that's logical, the action tries to render a view, if you're doing that call json, you can just do `render json: @device` if you loaded the current `device` in `device` of course

Comment: Hey so I put it like this, please let me know if this is correct?

Comment: ` def turnon

   @device = Device.find(params[:id])

   puts "/perl/toggle.pl"

   puts @device.infodot

   puts "off"

    result = `/perl/toggle.pl #{@device.infodot} off`

     respond_to do |format|

       format.json { render json: @device }

    end

    
  end

`

Comment: It was my typo , works like fairytale now. Question , it goes to blank page , how can I make it stay on the same page?

Comment: Well what do you exactly want to happen when the user clicks the link ?

Comment: OK, I made it work I want the method ran in back ground and then redraw html code for the particular line , now it works , but reloads the whole page.