# .toggle! returning "no route" ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

OK probably a newbie mistake but I hope someone can help me. Let me start off by apologizing for the nature of the example.
My app requires to know if a Dog is or isn't neutered and view this option in a list of dogs.

Example...
Dog1 | owner | Neutered
Dog2 | owner | Not neutered

The view looks great and even returns the properties properly the problem is when I click on the Neutered/Not neutered link it does not toggle the field in the Database and I get a Routing Erro No route matches [POST] "/dogs/3".

I have a database called Dog and it has a Boolean option :neutered 
I have in my dogs_controller.rb

> ...
>       def neuter
>         @dog = Dog.find(param[:id])
>         @dog.toggle!(:admin)
>         flash[:success] = "Changed Dog's neutered status"
>         redirect_to dogs_url
>       end
>       ...

In my routes.rb I have

> ...
>       resources :dogs do
>           member do
>           get :watching, :watchers  (used else where in program)
>         end
>       end
>   ...

in the partial that lists the dogs I have

> ...
>   <%= link_to dog.name, dog %>
>   <%= if dog.neutered? %>
>   <%= link_to "Neutered", dog, method: :neuter, data: { confirm: "This will mark the dog as neutered. Are you sure?" } %>
>   <% else %>
>   <%= link_to "Not Neutered", dog, method: :neuter, data: { confirm: "This will mark the dog as not neutered. Are you sure?" } %>
>   ...

So what am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to find it. I've tried several other options but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: can you post your model code ? I believe this is where the `toggle!` method is

Comment: and maybe have a look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149640/system-call-from-method-ruby-on-rails/13149777#13149777

Comment: toggle! should be a function inherent to an ActiveRecord::Base class shouldn't it? I can run dog.toggle!(neutered) in the console and it works fine. But no dice in the site. There is no reference to the toggle! function in my models/dog.rb file. If that's the fix then post as a solution so you can get the reputation ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple things going on here.

First, your `link_to` is incorrect if you want to link to the neuter action. You either need a named route:

```
<%= link_to "Neutered", neuter_dog_path(dog), method: :post %>
```

Or you need to specify the controller and action exactly:

```
<%= link_to "Neutered", controller: :dogs, action: :neuter, id: dog.id %>
```

Second, if you want to go for the named route, you need to add a section to your routes file.

```
resources :dogs do
  member do
    post :neuter
  end
end
```

Then the link should work correctly.

Comment: Specifying the controller didn't work but the named route option worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!